# XCode compile variables

Tags: ios, xcode6, preprocessor

I am developing a chat application. I am using Quickblox as backend as service. I have created 3 projects (each one different mode) on the admin panel : development, staging and production. Each mode has its specific properties. I want each mode to be activated as follows :

- Development : debug.
- Staging : client release.
- Production : app store deployment.

How can i achieve that automatically (via XCode) without having to change my global variables values depending on the mode ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the same app in three variations, right? In that case you should have *one* project with three targets. And you can do all kinds of build settings depending on the target. A trivial change is that in the debug target, DEBUG=1 would be defined while in the release it would not be defined.

Comment: Yes. The variables (urls and ids) are different in the three modes. So, should i have three targets in total ?

Comment: It should be one project with one target. Use the build configurations to determine which URLs to access.